# Print Core Data Results To New Controller and Send To Email

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

*** Edit * So my last question is, how to I get the data shown to be sent in email.  I have done much HTML email in my other apps, but am confused as to what I am asking to look for / reference from core data and the proper formatting of code...**

Using core date to populate UITable... all good... works as planned... (see pic 1) question... how can I get the result to format and and perhaps display as a UILabel on another controller similar to other results (see pic 2)... and then part two of my question... How can I get that result to print nicely in an email... I have used other code (not from coredata) to print and all works nicely together... I am stumped by the coredata portion...

In the result, you can see the math works out from core data, just don't know how to capture what the user typed in from core data (see pic 3)

Any help greatly appreciated...

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT (Clarification)...

I guess I want to show what the user has input into a new view controller and have it displayed in a readable format... (see image)...

[image]

Maybe my question is more... **how to I PASS the data THAT THE USER CREATED from the Core Data Table Model to a new view controller and display the incoming text as a UILabel?** (Can the new view controller be updated automatically? The user may add a new row, delete a row, change the hourly rate on an existing row, change a label etc. etc.. Once that is solved, I'd like to know how to send the results in an email so the end user can print for hard copy documentation... I have this scenario working in other apps, but they do not use core data...

Comment: I'm confused, it kind of sounds like you're asking how to fetch data from core data...but that doesn't make sense to me since you are already fetching it and displaying it in screen shot 1.  Can you clarify (or maybe just rephrase) please?

Comment: @ghostatron - I have edited my question... I guess, after the core data is added by user, I'd like to PASS it to a new view controller in a nice readable format... UILabel? Then how to send result in email...

Comment: If the data is in core data, then you don't need to pass that to the next view controller.  In that next view controller, just use viewDidLoad to request the data as shown in Apple's example: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html

Comment: To pass info about WHAT to fetch, you can implement prepareForSegue on your initial view controller.  i.e. on the 2nd one, have a property that is something like someDataIdentifier, in prepareForSegue, you have a chance to grab the 2nd view controller before it loads and you can assign a value to that property.  Then use that property to know what to fetch in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @ghostatron - this is awesome... got it to work based on your comment "if the data is in core data... just use viewDidLoad!  very easy... thank you for your help!